# Power series at the endpoints!

Tags: real-analysis

I am struggling with key concept for power series. Say we have a power series $f(x)$ centered at $c$ with radius of convergence $r>0$. If the series converges absolutely at $x=c-r$, does it have to converge at other endpoint $x=c+r$?

I know if it say "converges", then the statement would be false. It could converge at one endpoint and diverge at other. I have seen examples of that. But what does the "absolutely" part change? I believe still false, but I can't figure out a counter example. All the ones I have looked at that were divergent at right endpoint were only conditional convergent at the other. In general, what is a good way to build these power series how I want? Trial and error has not worked.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I have taken the liberty of upgrading your post with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please check to see that I did not unintentionally alter the meaning of any part of your question, and please attempt to use this formatting system in the future.

Comment: It look good! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If
$$
\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n (x-c)^n
$$
converges absolutely at $x = c-r$, this means the series
$$
\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n (c-r-c)^n = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n (-r)^n
$$
converges absolutely, that is
$$
\sum_{n\geq 0} |a_n| r^n
$$
converges. But for $x=c+r$, the original series is
$$
\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n (c+r-c)^n = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n r^n,
$$
so it converges absolutely as well.

Comment: Took the absolute value, and $r > 0$.

Comment: No, for the same reason: absolute convergence at $x=c \pm r$ means convergence of $\sum |a_n| r^n$.

Comment: And to follow up on your earlier comment: I did not took the absolute value of the sum, but the sum of the absolute values. This is what absolute convergence means!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if a power series converges **absolutely** at one and point, it converges **absolutely** at the other. If a power series converges at one end point and diverges at the other, it can only **conditionally** converge at that end point.

If a power series converges absolutely at one and point, it converges absolutely at the other.
**Proof**
A power series converges absolutely at one end point.
Therefore either $\sum a_n(-r)^n$ or $\sum a_nr^n$ converges absolutely.
Therefore $\sum \lvert a_n(-r)^n \rvert$ converges.
Therefore it converges absolutely at the other endpoint.